# JavaScript code for onclick event and it does not run on firefox(ver.68.0.1) and chrome(75.0)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Firefox(ver.68.0.1) and  Chrome(ver.75.0) are unable to execute the script. Click on the "Click Me" button does not execute the `behave()` method which is supposed to pop-up an alert message "Click is Completed".

I have tried using "onclick" and "onsubmit"

### HTML file(jsb-06.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
         <title> Event Handler through a Button</title>
         <script="text/javascript" src="jsb-06.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form action="">
              <div>
                     <button  id="action">Click Me</button>
              </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JS file("jsb-06.js")

```
// tell the JS to run this script when the browser has finished loading the page
window.onload = applyBehaviour();

// define a function and apply its behaviour

function applyBehaviour() {

    // ensure a DOM aware user agent

    if (document.getElementById) {

        var oButton = document.getElementById("action");

        // if it exists apply behaviour

        if (oButton) {

            oButton.onsubmit = behave();
        }
    }
}

// what to do when the button is clicked

function behave() {

    alert("Click is Completed !!");

}
```

### Expected result:

Browser pops-up an alert message box with the message-"Click is Completed"

### Actual result:

Browser doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

`onsubmit` is an event triggered by the form, not the button. Try to change to `onclick`:

```
oButton.onclick = behave;
```

or attach the event to the form:

```
document.getElementById("the-id-of-your-form").onsubmit = behave;
```

Note that I removed the `()` from the examples above. That was done because we are not executing the function, but linking it to the event.

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/dazakamexa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: tried both, as you have suggested but it does not work .same response from the browser as described before.

Comment: @DivyenduDeo I added an example. Try the JSBin link above.

Comment: also i have tried to execute by removing the parenthesis() , still not working as expected.

Comment: where is the "JSBin " link.

Comment: In the end of the answer (I just edited it). And removing the parenthesis is mandatory in this case.

Comment: @DivyenduDeo You're welcome! If it works, do not forget to accept the answer in the system, ok? That will be helpful for other users in the future.

Comment: but why am i facing a problem executing it on my browser window. the code works fine on your link, but seems to have a problem executing on my system.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser's console? What changes did you make after the example in the question?

Comment: no error message on the browser console. no changes made ,just executed the code after making necessary changes suggested by you.

Comment: Checking if I understood correctly: you opened the link and it worked, but when you copied to your own code in your computer it is not working, right? If yes, check the following: (1) are there any duplicated IDs in your page? (IDs must be unique in HTML), (2) are you sure you removed all the parenthesis while setting the events?, (3) are you sure there are no typos in the IDs in the HTML or in the JavaScript?

Comment: checked everything as suggested:(1) no duplicate IDs (2)removed all parenthesis (3) no typos at all in the HTML and JS file.

Comment: Could you create a new jsbin and try to replicate your issue there? Start from scratch and paste your code. Then share the link here.

Comment: @DivyenduDeo Change `onsubmit` to `onclick` and the code will work.

Comment: As i have already elucidated before that i have tried both. but none of them executes as one would expect them to.

Comment: No,it doesn't work.Am I missing some library files that i need to load on my system  in order to execute   the code ?

Comment: @DivyenduDeo I noticed I shared the wrong link. Forgot to save. Try this one now: https://jsbin.com/gocotocafu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: window.onload=applyBehaviour;  should be the first line of the file,beacuse it tells the browser to run the script after the page (document) has finished loading.but in the link that u have shared it is the last line ; although it works fine in the link that u have shared but it doesn't work on my browser.